# How can i access windows XP remote desktop on private IP from internet?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

So the machine is behind a DSL router on a private IP so that it can not receive inbound requests. I want to know:

1. Is there anyway to setup the router NAT (i highly doubt it supports one to one port mapping) without disturbing other users on the same router.
2. I have another machine on internet which has public IP on it without any firewall. Can i use this machine as a relay server so that to initiate the connection, the XP machine send an outbound request and this relay server makes my connection through and then i can access my machine on pvt ip without any problem.

Please tell??

Comment: Logmein or similar solutions

Comment: Do you have access to create inbound routes from the DSL router to your internal network?

Answer (score 2):

Jennie, there are many solutions to this issue. By access are you looking for a remote desktop solution?

You could NAT the remote desktop ports via the router to your desktop.

You could have a system on a public IP allow remote desktop and if it is connected to your LAN, you could initiate a second remote desktop through your public computer.

There are also commercial solutions to this issue such as Remote Desktop Services, GoToMyPC or LogMeIn that doesn't require any remote desktop or NAT issues and will work for multiple PCs/servers within the same LAN.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com). It's free, cross platform and works great.